# How to get newsletter subscribers

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, newsletter

I'm trying to get newsletter subscribers using the code:

```
$subscribers = Mage::getModel('newsletter/subscriber')->getCollection();
```

but it is empty. 
Where I'm wrong? thanks

Comment: Are you sure there are any subscribers in the first place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will show last 10 newsletter subscribers:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('newsletter/subscriber')->getCollection()
    ->setPageSize(10)
    ->setOrder('subscriber_id', 'desc');

foreach ($collection as $subscriber) {
    Zend_Debug::dump($subscriber->getData());
}
```

Look at `Mage_Newsletter_Model_Resource_Subscriber_Collection` to see which methods are available. Also look at `newsletter_subscriber` table.

Answer (score 1):

1. Check in the magento backend for the site that there are actual subscribers.
2. Are you loading the required magento file at `app/Mage.php`?
3. Are you looping over the items in that collection somehow? You'll probably need to do a foreach loop on it like this:

   `foreach ($subscribers as $subscriber){
       if ($subscriber->getSubscriberStatus()){
           // Do something with $subscriber->getSubscriberEmail();
       }
   }`

Answer (score 0):

This is a more efficient way to do it:

```
$newsletterSubscribers = Mage::getResourceModel('newsletter/subscriber_collection')
        ->addFieldToFilter('subscriber_status', array ('eq' => 1)); // 1 is subscribed
```